# Is there a library for image warping / image morphing for python with controlled points?

Tags: python, image-processing, image-manipulation

You'd take images and mark specific points (for example, mark the region around the eyes, nose, mouth etc of people) and then transform them into the points marked into another image. Something like:

```
transform(original_image, marked_points_in_the_original, marked_points_in_the_reference)
```

I can't seem to find an algorithm describing it, nor can I find any libraries with it. I'm willing to do it myself too, as long as I can find good/easy to follow material on it. I know it's possible though since I've seen some incomplete (don't really explain how to do it) .pdfs on google with it.

Here's an example of the marked points and the transformation, since you asked for clarification. Though this one isn't using 2 people as I said earlier.

[image]
[image]

Edit: I managed to get the `im.transform` method working, but the argument is a list of `((box_x, box_y, box_width, box_height), (x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3))`, with the first point being NW, the second SW, the third NE and the fourth SE. (0, 0) is the leftmost upper part of the screen as far as I could tell. If I did everything right, then this method doesn't really do what I need.

Comment: "transform" is a vague word. Can you explain what you mean? Do you want to copy parts of one image and "paste" them directly into another? What kind of region?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/pillow/imageops-deforming/

Answer (score 13):

Sample code given by Blender doesn't work for me. Also, the PIL documentation for `im.transform` is ambiguous. So I dig into the PIL source code and finally figure out how to use the interface. Here's my complete usage:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def quad_as_rect(quad):
    if quad[0] != quad[2]: return False
    if quad[1] != quad[7]: return False
    if quad[4] != quad[6]: return False
    if quad[3] != quad[5]: return False
    return True

def quad_to_rect(quad):
    assert(len(quad) == 8)
    assert(quad_as_rect(quad))
    return (quad[0], quad[1], quad[4], quad[3])

def rect_to_quad(rect):
    assert(len(rect) == 4)
    return (rect[0], rect[1], rect[0], rect[3], rect[2], rect[3], rect[2], rect[1])

def shape_to_rect(shape):
    assert(len(shape) == 2)
    return (0, 0, shape[0], shape[1])

def griddify(rect, w_div, h_div):
    w = rect[2] - rect[0]
    h = rect[3] - rect[1]
    x_step = w / float(w_div)
    y_step = h / float(h_div)
    y = rect[1]
    grid_vertex_matrix = []
    for _ in range(h_div + 1):
        grid_vertex_matrix.append([])
        x = rect[0]
        for _ in range(w_div + 1):
            grid_vertex_matrix[-1].append([int(x), int(y)])
            x += x_step
        y += y_step
    grid = np.array(grid_vertex_matrix)
    return grid

def distort_grid(org_grid, max_shift):
    new_grid = np.copy(org_grid)
    x_min = np.min(new_grid[:, :, 0])
    y_min = np.min(new_grid[:, :, 1])
    x_max = np.max(new_grid[:, :, 0])
    y_max = np.max(new_grid[:, :, 1])
    new_grid += np.random.randint(- max_shift, max_shift + 1, new_grid.shape)
    new_grid[:, :, 0] = np.maximum(x_min, new_grid[:, :, 0])
    new_grid[:, :, 1] = np.maximum(y_min, new_grid[:, :, 1])
    new_grid[:, :, 0] = np.minimum(x_max, new_grid[:, :, 0])
    new_grid[:, :, 1] = np.minimum(y_max, new_grid[:, :, 1])
    return new_grid

def grid_to_mesh(src_grid, dst_grid):
    assert(src_grid.shape == dst_grid.shape)
    mesh = []
    for i in range(src_grid.shape[0] - 1):
        for j in range(src_grid.shape[1] - 1):
            src_quad = [src_grid[i    , j    , 0], src_grid[i    , j    , 1],
                        src_grid[i + 1, j    , 0], src_grid[i + 1, j    , 1],
                        src_grid[i + 1, j + 1, 0], src_grid[i + 1, j + 1, 1],
                        src_grid[i    , j + 1, 0], src_grid[i    , j + 1, 1]]
            dst_quad = [dst_grid[i    , j    , 0], dst_grid[i    , j    , 1],
                        dst_grid[i + 1, j    , 0], dst_grid[i + 1, j    , 1],
                        dst_grid[i + 1, j + 1, 0], dst_grid[i + 1, j + 1, 1],
                        dst_grid[i    , j + 1, 0], dst_grid[i    , j + 1, 1]]
            dst_rect = quad_to_rect(dst_quad)
            mesh.append([dst_rect, src_quad])
    return mesh

im = Image.open('./old_driver/data/train/c0/img_292.jpg')
dst_grid = griddify(shape_to_rect(im.size), 4, 4)
src_grid = distort_grid(dst_grid, 50)
mesh = grid_to_mesh(src_grid, dst_grid)
im = im.transform(im.size, Image.MESH, mesh)
im.show()
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

I suggest executing above code in iPython then print out `mesh` to  understand what kind of input is needed for `im.transform`. For me the output is:

```
In [1]: mesh
Out[1]:
[[(0, 0, 160, 120), [0, 29, 29, 102, 186, 120, 146, 0]],
 [(160, 0, 320, 120), [146, 0, 186, 120, 327, 127, 298, 48]],
 [(320, 0, 480, 120), [298, 48, 327, 127, 463, 77, 492, 26]],
 [(480, 0, 640, 120), [492, 26, 463, 77, 640, 80, 605, 0]],
 [(0, 120, 160, 240), [29, 102, 9, 241, 162, 245, 186, 120]],
 [(160, 120, 320, 240), [186, 120, 162, 245, 339, 214, 327, 127]],
 [(320, 120, 480, 240), [327, 127, 339, 214, 513, 284, 463, 77]],
 [(480, 120, 640, 240), [463, 77, 513, 284, 607, 194, 640, 80]],
 [(0, 240, 160, 360), [9, 241, 27, 364, 202, 365, 162, 245]],
 [(160, 240, 320, 360), [162, 245, 202, 365, 363, 315, 339, 214]],
 [(320, 240, 480, 360), [339, 214, 363, 315, 453, 373, 513, 284]],
 [(480, 240, 640, 360), [513, 284, 453, 373, 640, 319, 607, 194]],
 [(0, 360, 160, 480), [27, 364, 33, 478, 133, 480, 202, 365]],
 [(160, 360, 320, 480), [202, 365, 133, 480, 275, 480, 363, 315]],
 [(320, 360, 480, 480), [363, 315, 275, 480, 434, 469, 453, 373]],
 [(480, 360, 640, 480), [453, 373, 434, 469, 640, 462, 640, 319]]]
```

Comment: how do you specify which parts of the image to be deformed though?

Answer (score 8):

On a similar note, you could use ImageMagick's Python API to do [Shepards's Distortion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards).

[image: koala ears]
[image: koala ears pull]

Comment: This seems similar to what I'm trying to do. I'll give it a try and report back if I manage to get it working.

Comment: ImageMagick works, but the results I got weren't as good as I had hoped.

Comment: this works pretty well for creating animated gifs. i applied gradual shepard's distortions with changing alpha for two images and the result looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/1Lh4i.gif

thanks for the tip!

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza in fact here is the final product :) http://muratayfer.com/morphin/ all thanks to this thread.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, there is. It's a bit low-level, but [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (the Python Imaging Library) has a function to do this sort of transformation. I've never really had it work for me (as my problem was a bit simpler), but you can play with it.

Here's a good resource for the PIL transformations (you'd want to look at **MESH**): http://effbot.org/tag/PIL.Image.Image.transform.

---

From the documentation:

> > Similar to QUAD, but **data** is a list of target rectangles and corresponding source quadrilaterals.

```
im.transform(size, MESH, data)
```

Data is a tuple of rectangles:

```
data = [((a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h)), 
        ((i, j, k, l), (m, n, o, p))]
```

It transforms the first rectangle into the second.

Comment: I've read that documentation before but I don't understand what goes in that function. Could you explain its parameters? If I'm reading it correctly, all I have to do is create a map with the original coordinates -> new coordinates and pass it as a MESH and it works?

Comment: More or less. The `mesh` has to consist of pairs of rectangles, but you can make degenerate `1x1` rectangles. The larger the size, the faster it goes.

Answer (score 6):

I've got a solution using OpenCV by triangulating the transformation points:
[image: Transformation]

It does not look perfect, but with more points on the source/target image the results get better.

## Code

Here is the code I used for the transformation, at the bottom you can see how to call your `transform` function.

```
#!/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_triangulation_indices(points):
    """Get indices triples for every triangle
    """
    # Bounding rectangle
    bounding_rect = (*points.min(axis=0), *points.max(axis=0))

    # Triangulate all points
    subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D(bounding_rect)
    subdiv.insert(list(points))

    # Iterate over all triangles
    for x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 in subdiv.getTriangleList():
        # Get index of all points
        yield [(points==point).all(axis=1).nonzero()[0][0] for point in [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)]]

def crop_to_triangle(img, triangle):
    """Crop image to triangle
    """
    # Get bounding rectangle
    bounding_rect = cv2.boundingRect(triangle)

    # Crop image to bounding box
    img_cropped = img[bounding_rect[1]:bounding_rect[1] + bounding_rect[3],
                      bounding_rect[0]:bounding_rect[0] + bounding_rect[2]]
    # Move triangle to coordinates in cropped image
    triangle_cropped = [(point[0]-bounding_rect[0], point[1]-bounding_rect[1]) for point in triangle]
    return triangle_cropped, img_cropped

def transform(src_img, src_points, dst_img, dst_points): 
    """Transforms source image to target image, overwriting the target image.
    """
    for indices in get_triangulation_indices(src_points):
        # Get triangles from indices
        src_triangle = src_points[indices]
        dst_triangle = dst_points[indices]

        # Crop to triangle, to make calculations more efficient
        src_triangle_cropped, src_img_cropped = crop_to_triangle(src_img, src_triangle)
        dst_triangle_cropped, dst_img_cropped = crop_to_triangle(dst_img, dst_triangle)

        # Calculate transfrom to warp from old image to new
        transform = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(src_triangle_cropped), np.float32(dst_triangle_cropped))

        # Warp image
        dst_img_warped = cv2.warpAffine(src_img_cropped, transform, (dst_img_cropped.shape[1], dst_img_cropped.shape[0]), None, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101 )

        # Create mask for the triangle we want to transform
        mask = np.zeros(dst_img_cropped.shape, dtype = np.uint8)
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.int32(dst_triangle_cropped), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 16, 0);

        # Delete all existing pixels at given mask
        dst_img_cropped*=1-mask
        # Add new pixels to masked area
        dst_img_cropped+=dst_img_warped*mask

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Inputs
    src_img = cv2.imread("woman.jpg")
    dst_img = cv2.imread("cheetah.jpg")
    src_points = np.array([(40, 27), (38, 65), (47, 115), (66, 147), (107, 166), (147, 150), (172, 118), (177, 75), (173, 26), (63, 19), (89, 30), (128, 34), (152, 27), (75, 46), (142, 46), (109, 48), (95, 96), (107, 91), (120, 97), (84, 123), (106, 117), (132, 121), (97, 137), (107, 139), (120, 135)])
    dst_points = np.array([(2, 16), (0, 60), (2, 143), (47, 181), (121, 178), (208, 181), (244, 133), (241, 87), (241, 18), (41, 15), (73, 20), (174, 16), (218, 16), (56, 23), (191, 23), (120, 48), (94, 128), (120, 122), (150, 124), (83, 174), (122, 164), (159, 173), (110, 174), (121, 174), (137, 175)])

    # Apply transformation
    transform(src_img, src_points, dst_img, dst_points)

    # Show result
    cv2.imshow("Transformed", dst_img)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The `src_points` and `dst_points` in the main-Function were hardcoded and correspond to the landmarks, that are marked green in the images above. The code was partly inspired by [this](https://pysource.com/2019/05/28/face-swapping-explained-in-8-steps-opencv-with-python/) online article, but the code was clean up a bit. After answering this question, I've also created my own [FaceChanger github repo](https://github.com/pascscha/FaceChanger), with an interactive python app, using the same functionality as described in this answer.

## Requirements

- [Numpy](https://numpy.org/install/): `pip3 install numpy`
- [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html): `pip3 install opencv-python`

## How it works

### Triangulation

At first we need to triangulate the image, which will transform the points from the two top images to the triangles at the bottom. We need triangles instead of points because this allows us to transform the individual triangles seperately, which will make our live easier down the road. The triangulation is done using [Delaunay Triangluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) with OpenCV. The points of the first and the second image do not necessarily have to result in the same triangulation, therefore the `get_triangulation_indices` function returns the indices of all corners for each triangle. Using these indices we can map every source triangle to one destination triangle

### Warp Triangles

The triangles are warped using OpenCV's `warpAffine`-method. The issue with this method is that it warps an entire image and not just one triangle, so we have to do some more work there to only warp triangles.

#### Cut out triangle

First we cut out only the part of the source and target image that contains the source or target triangle. This would theoretically not be necessary, but it's much faster that way because then we don't have to do the warp on the entire image everytime. This is done using the `crop_to_triangle`-method.

#### Transform image

Then we see how we have to distort the image to get from the source triangle to the target triangle, with `cv2.getAffineTransform`. This will give us a transformation matrix that we can use with `cv2.warpAffine` to warp our image to the destination proportions.

#### Mask to triangle

Now we have the issue that the warp transform did not just transform our triangles, but our entire `src_img_cropped`. So now we have to only past the pixels belonging to our triangle to the target image. We can use `cv2.fillConvexPoly` to create a mask of our target triangle and use this to delete all pixels from the destination image that are within the triangle that we want to paste, in order to add the warped triangle to this spot that we just emptied. This is done using Numpy array manipulations.

## Conclusion

This is a fairly simple method to achieve the task. It does however result in some unnatural looking straight edges sometimes, and might therefore not be perfect for all uses. The quality of the result is however increased if you add more points to your source and target images. You also need to add the corners of the source and target images to your points if you want that the entire image is copied, otherwise the destination image will just be overwritten with parts of the source image, which I see as a feature. This can also be combined with face detection to create a face-swap effect, for which I personally use [dlib](https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-face-features-with-python-30385aee4a8e), which gives great results.

Comment: This should go down in history as one of the greatest StackOverflow answers ever! I'm working on a super important personal project right now, and I've been looking for something like this for *ages*. If I wanted to learn more in depth about this methodology, do you have any recommendations for courses/resources online where I could look for more info? I'm familiar with homography and other global image warping ops, but I'm brand new to local morphing.