# How can I compute the location of a specific point after a mesh transformation in Python PIL (Pillow)?

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

If I transform image using:

This code was taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350619/259757

```
im_transformed = im.transform(im.size, Image.MESH, mesh)
```

Given a specific coordinate (x,y) from my original image how can I compute what the new coordinates would be in im_transformed? Basically could I apply the same transformation to a specific single point like is possible with affine transformations?

My reason for wanting to do this is that lets say I have the location known of a smily face in the image. In the second image that has been transformed/warped I want to make a prediction where where that smily face is and compare the prediction to where it should be. I know its not exact but the idea is that I can generate clean image with known locations of smily face, warp them and have a new location in x,y where the smily face should be in the warped image. This will allow me to generate training data for a machine learning model.

With an affine transformation this is pretty straightforward but with a mesh transformation I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

So after a little digging in PIL code this is what i could find:

A MESH transform is just a multiple application of QUAD transforms.

Each QUAD transform maps a quadrilateral in the source image to a rectangle in the destination.

So lets see what a QUAD transform is: [PIL quad transform](https://github.com/whatupdave/pil/blob/master/libImaging/Geometry.c)

```
   quad_transform(double* xin, double* yin, int x, int y, void* data) {

    double* a = (double*) data;
    double a0 = a[0]; double a1 = a[1]; double a2 = a[2]; double a3 = a[3];
    double a4 = a[4]; double a5 = a[5]; double a6 = a[6]; double a7 = a[7];

    xin[0] = a0 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*x*y;
    yin[0] = a4 + a5*x + a6*y + a7*x*y;

    return 1;
}
```

This is an inverse mapping that tells how to sample a point in the source image to get the pixel in the location xin,yin in the target image.

The parameters are calculated in the following way and i rewrote it so it looks nicer:

```
def get_parameters(rectangle, quadrilateral):
 w = rectangle[2] - rectangle[0]
 h = rectangle[3] - rectangle[1]

 nw = quadrilateral[0:2]  # The quadrilateral coordinates
 sw = quadrilateral[2:4]  # The quadrilateral coordinates
 se = quadrilateral[4:6]  # The quadrilateral coordinates
 ne = quadrilateral[6:8]  # The quadrilateral coordinates
 x0, y0 = nw
 As = 1.0 / w
 At = 1.0 / h
 parameters = (
    x0,  # a0
    (ne[0] - x0) * As,  # a1,
    (sw[0] - x0) * At,  # a2
    (se[0] - sw[0] - ne[0] + x0) * As * At,  # a3
    y0,  # a4
    (ne[1] - y0) * As,  # a5
    (sw[1] - y0) * At,  # a6
    (se[1] - sw[1] - ne[1] + y0) * As * At,  # a7
 )
 return parameters
```

The problem is that you want the transformation from the point in the QUAD to the resulted point in the rectangle.

So you need to solve the following equations for x and y (not for x_rect and y_rect !!!!):

```
x_rect = a0 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*x*y;
y_rect = a4 + a5*x + a6*y + a7*x*y;
```

This inversion is not the nicest and gives you a quadratic equation in x and y so you will need to decide which solution to take according to the resulting coordinates.

For a full explanation please look at [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924753/what-is-the-inverse-of-this-transformation-from-a-rectangle-to-a-quadrilateral)